# Как исправить ошибку компиляции Android x86?

Tags: android, x86

у меня возникла ошибка компиляции, код:

```
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL

PLATFORM_VERSION=9

TARGET_PRODUCT=android_x86_64

TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug

TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release

TARGET_ARCH=x86_64

TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64

TARGET_2ND_ARCH=x86

TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64

HOST_ARCH=x86_64

HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86

HOST_OS=linux

HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.0.0-25-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-18.04.3-LTS

HOST_CROSS_OS=windows

HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86

HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64

HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release

BUILD_ID=PQ2A.190305.002

OUT_DIR=out

============================================

[1/1] out/soong/.minibootstrap/minibp out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja

[44/45] glob prebuilts/ndk/stl.bp

[77/77] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja

out/build-android_x86_64-cleanspec.ninja is missing, regenerating...

out/build-android_x86_64.ninja is missing, regenerating...

[25/567] including development/build/Android.mk ...

development/build/build_android_stubs.mk:43: warning: android_stubs_current 

development/build/build_android_stubs.mk:43: warning: metalava_android_stubs_current metalava_android_stubs_current

development/build/build_android_stubs.mk:43: warning: android_system_stubs_current 

development/build/build_android_stubs.mk:43: warning: android_test_stubs_current 

development/build/build_android_stubs.mk:43: warning: metalava_android_system_stubs_current metalava_android_system_stubs_current

development/build/build_android_stubs.mk:43: warning: metalava_android_test_stubs_current metalava_android_test_stubs_current

[499/567] including system/sepolicy/Android.mk ...

system/sepolicy/Android.mk:79: warning: BOARD_SEPOLICY_VERS not specified, assuming current platform version

[567/567] including tools/test/connectivity/Android.mk ...

[ 99% 798/799] glob frameworks/base/core/res/res/**/*

[  0% 147/99166] build out/target/comm...e-oj_intermediates/annotated/timestamp

WARNING: duplicate annotation of type libcore.util.NonNull

WARNING: duplicate annotation of type libcore.util.NonNull

Found class java.io.PrintWriter, but unable to insert @libcore.util.NonNull:

  @libcore.util.NonNull (nl=false) @ {GENERIC_ARRAY_LOCATION=GenericArrayLocationCriterion at outermost type, RETURN_TYPE=ReturnTypeCriterion for method: append(C)Ljava/io/Writer;, IN_METHOD=in method 'append(C)Ljava/io/Writer;', IN_CLASS=In class 'java.io.PrintWriter' (exactly)}

Found class java.io.PrintWriter, but unable to insert @libcore.util.NonNull:

  @libcore.util.NonNull (nl=false) @ {GENERIC_ARRAY_LOCATION=GenericArrayLocationCriterion at outermost type, RETURN_TYPE=ReturnTypeCriterion for method: append(C)Ljava/lang/Appendable;, IN_METHOD=in method 'append(C)Ljava/lang/Appendable;', IN_CLASS=In class 'java.io.PrintWriter' (exactly)}

Found class java.io.PrintWriter, but unable to insert @libcore.util.NonNull:

  @libcore.util.NonNull (nl=false) @ {GENERIC_ARRAY_LOCATION=GenericArrayLocationCriterion at outermost type, RETURN_TYPE=ReturnTypeCriterion for method: append(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Ljava/io/Writer;, IN_METHOD=in method 'append(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Ljava/io/Writer;', IN_CLASS=In class 'java.io.PrintWriter' (exactly)}

Found class java.io.PrintWriter, but unable to insert @libcore.util.Nullable:

  @libcore.util.Nullable (nl=false) @ {GENERIC_ARRAY_LOCATION=GenericArrayLocationCriterion at outermost type, PARAM=ParamCriterion for method: append(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;) at position: 0, IN_METHOD=in method 'append(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Ljava/io/Writer;', IN_CLASS=In class 'java.io.PrintWriter' (exactly)}

Found class java.io.PrintWriter, but unable to insert @libcore.util.NonNull:

  @libcore.util.NonNull (nl=false) @ {GENERIC_ARRAY_LOCATION=GenericArrayLocationCriterion at outermost type, RETURN_TYPE=ReturnTypeCriterion for method: append(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Ljava/lang/Appendable;, IN_METHOD=in method 'append(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Ljava/lang/Appendable;', IN_CLASS=In class 'java.io.PrintWriter' (exactly)}

Found class java.io.PrintWriter, but unable to insert @libcore.util.Nullable:

  @libcore.util.Nullable (nl=false) @ {GENERIC_ARRAY_LOCATION=GenericArrayLocationCriterion at outermost type, PARAM=ParamCriterion for method: append(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;) at position: 0, IN_METHOD=in method 'append(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Ljava/lang/Appendable;', IN_CLASS=In class 'java.io.PrintWriter' (exactly)}

Found class java.io.PrintWriter, but unable to insert @libcore.util.NonNull:

  @libcore.util.NonNull (nl=false) @ {GENERIC_ARRAY_LOCATION=GenericArrayLocationCriterion at outermost type, RETURN_TYPE=ReturnTypeCriterion for method: append(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;II)Ljava/io/Writer;, IN_METHOD=in method 'append(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;II)Ljava/io/Writer;', IN_CLASS=In class 'java.io.PrintWriter' (exactly)}

Found class java.io.PrintWriter, but unable to insert @libcore.util.Nullable:

  @libcore.util.Nullable (nl=false) @ {GENERIC_ARRAY_LOCATION=GenericArrayLocationCriterion at outermost type, PARAM=ParamCriterion for method: append(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;II) at position: 0, IN_METHOD=in method 'append(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;II)Ljava/io/Writer;', IN_CLASS=In class 'java.io.PrintWriter' (exactly)}

Found class java.io.PrintWriter, but unable to insert @libcore.util.NonNull:

  @libcore.util.NonNull (nl=false) @ {GENERIC_ARRAY_LOCATION=GenericArrayLocationCriterion at outermost type, RETURN_TYPE=ReturnTypeCriterion for method: append(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;II)Ljava/lang/Appendable;, IN_METHOD=in method 'append(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;II)Ljava/lang/Appendable;', IN_CLASS=In class 'java.io.PrintWriter' (exactly)}

Found class java.io.PrintWriter, but unable to insert @libcore.util.Nullable:

  @libcore.util.Nullable (nl=false) @ {GENERIC_ARRAY_LOCATION=GenericArrayLocationCriterion at outermost type, PARAM=ParamCriterion for method: append(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;II) at position: 0, IN_METHOD=in method 'append(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;II)Ljava/lang/Appendable;', IN_CLASS=In class 'java.io.PrintWriter' (exactly)}

Found class java.util.HashMap, but unable to insert @libcore.util.NonNull:

  @libcore.util.NonNull (nl=false) @ {GENERIC_ARRAY_LOCATION=GenericArrayLocationCriterion at ( [TYPE_ARGUMENT(0)] ), RETURN_TYPE=ReturnTypeCriterion for method: entrySet()Ljava/util/Set;, IN_METHOD=in method 'entrySet()Ljava/util/Set;', IN_CLASS=In class 'java.util.HashMap' (exactly)}

Found class java.util.HashMap, but unable to insert @libcore.util.NullFromTypeParam:

  @libcore.util.NullFromTypeParam (nl=false) @ {GENERIC_ARRAY_LOCATION=GenericArrayLocationCriterion at ( [TYPE_ARGUMENT(0), TYPE_ARGUMENT(0)] ), RETURN_TYPE=ReturnTypeCriterion for method: entrySet()Ljava/util/Set;, IN_METHOD=in method 'entrySet()Ljava/util/Set;', IN_CLASS=In class 'java.util.HashMap' (exactly)}

Found class java.util.HashMap, but unable to insert @libcore.util.NullFromTypeParam:

  @libcore.util.NullFromTypeParam (nl=false) @ {GENERIC_ARRAY_LOCATION=GenericArrayLocationCriterion at ( [TYPE_ARGUMENT(0), TYPE_ARGUMENT(1)] ), RETURN_TYPE=ReturnTypeCriterion for method: entrySet()Ljava/util/Set;, IN_METHOD=in method 'entrySet()Ljava/util/Set;', IN_CLASS=In class 'java.util.HashMap' (exactly)}

[  0% 879/99166] build out/target/prod...ws_intermediates/reqd_policy_mask.conf

FAILED: out/target/product/x86_64/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/reqd_policy_mask.conf 

/bin/bash -c "m4  -D mls_num_sens=1 -D mls_num_cats=1024 -D target_build_variant=userdebug -D target_with_dexpreopt=true -D target_arch=x86_64 -D target_with_asan=false -D target_full_treble=false -D target_compatible_property=false  -s system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/security_classes system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/initial_sids system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/access_vectors system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/mls_macros system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/mls_decl system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/mls system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/reqd_mask.te system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/roles_decl system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/roles system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/users system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/initial_sid_contexts > out/target/product/x86_64/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/reqd_policy_mask.conf"

/bin/bash: m4: команда не найдена

[  0% 880/99166] build out/target/prod...ows_intermediates/plat_pub_policy.conf

FAILED: out/target/product/x86_64/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/plat_pub_policy.conf 

/bin/bash -c "m4  -D mls_num_sens=1 -D mls_num_cats=1024 -D target_build_variant=userdebug -D target_with_dexpreopt=true -D target_arch=x86_64 -D target_with_asan=false -D target_full_treble=false -D target_compatible_property=false  -s system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/security_classes system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/initial_sids system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/access_vectors system/sepolicy/public/global_macros system/sepolicy/public/neverallow_macros system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/mls_macros system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/mls_decl system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/mls system/sepolicy/public/te_macros system/sepolicy/public/attributes system/sepolicy/public/ioctl_defines system/sepolicy/public/ioctl_macros system/sepolicy/public/adbd.te system/sepolicy/public/app.te system/sepolicy/public/asan_extract.te system/sepolicy/public/audioserver.te system/sepolicy/public/blkid.te system/sepolicy/public/blkid_untrusted.te system/sepolicy/public/bluetooth.te system/sepolicy/public/bootanim.te system/sepolicy/public/bootstat.te system/sepolicy/public/bufferhubd.te system/sepolicy/public/cameraserver.te system/sepolicy/public/charger.te system/sepolicy/public/clatd.te system/sepolicy/public/cppreopts.te system/sepolicy/public/crash_dump.te system/sepolicy/public/device.te system/sepolicy/public/dex2oat.te system/sepolicy/public/dhcp.te system/sepolicy/public/display_service_server.te system/sepolicy/public/dnsmasq.te system/sepolicy/public/domain.te system/sepolicy/public/drmserver.te system/sepolicy/public/dumpstate.te system/sepolicy/public/e2fs.te system/sepolicy/public/ephemeral_app.te system/sepolicy/public/file.te system/sepolicy/public/fingerprintd.te system/sepolicy/public/fsck.te system/sepolicy/public/fsck_untrusted.te system/sepolicy/public/gatekeeperd.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_allocator.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_audio.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_audiocontrol.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_authsecret.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_bluetooth.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_bootctl.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_broadcastradio.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_camera.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_cas.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_configstore.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_confirmationui.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_contexthub.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_drm.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_dumpstate.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_evs.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_fingerprint.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_gatekeeper.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_gnss.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_graphics_allocator.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_graphics_composer.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_health.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_ir.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_keymaster.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_light.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_lowpan.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_memtrack.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_neuralnetworks.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_neverallows.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_nfc.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_oemlock.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_power.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_secure_element.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_sensors.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_telephony.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_tetheroffload.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_thermal.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_tv_cec.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_tv_input.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_usb.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_usb_gadget.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_vehicle.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_vibrator.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_vr.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_weaver.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_wifi.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_wifi_hostapd.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_wifi_offload.te system/sepolicy/public/hal_wifi_supplicant.te system/sepolicy/public/healthd.te system/sepolicy/public/hwservice.te system/sepolicy/public/hwservicemanager.te system/sepolicy/public/idmap.te system/sepolicy/public/incident.te system/sepolicy/public/incident_helper.te system/sepolicy/public/incidentd.te system/sepolicy/public/init.te system/sepolicy/public/inputflinger.te system/sepolicy/public/install_recovery.te system/sepolicy/public/installd.te system/sepolicy/public/isolated_app.te system/sepolicy/public/kernel.te system/sepolicy/public/keystore.te system/sepolicy/public/lmkd.te system/sepolicy/public/logd.te system/sepolicy/public/logpersist.te system/sepolicy/public/mdnsd.te system/sepolicy/public/mediacodec.te system/sepolicy/public/mediadrmserver.te system/sepolicy/public/mediaextractor.te system/sepolicy/public/mediametrics.te system/sepolicy/public/mediaprovider.te system/sepolicy/public/mediaserver.te system/sepolicy/public/modprobe.te system/sepolicy/public/mtp.te system/sepolicy/public/net.te system/sepolicy/public/netd.te system/sepolicy/public/netutils_wrapper.te system/sepolicy/public/nfc.te system/sepolicy/public/otapreopt_chroot.te system/sepolicy/public/otapreopt_slot.te system/sepolicy/public/performanced.te system/sepolicy/public/perfprofd.te system/sepolicy/public/platform_app.te system/sepolicy/public/postinstall.te system/sepolicy/public/postinstall_dexopt.te system/sepolicy/public/ppp.te system/sepolicy/public/preopt2cachename.te system/sepolicy/public/priv_app.te system/sepolicy/public/profman.te system/sepolicy/public/property.te system/sepolicy/public/racoon.te system/sepolicy/public/radio.te system/sepolicy/public/recovery.te system/sepolicy/public/recovery_persist.te system/sepolicy/public/recovery_refresh.te system/sepolicy/public/runas.te system/sepolicy/public/sdcardd.te system/sepolicy/public/secure_element.te system/sepolicy/public/service.te system/sepolicy/public/servicemanager.te system/sepolicy/public/sgdisk.te system/sepolicy/public/shared_relro.te system/sepolicy/public/shell.te system/sepolicy/public/slideshow.te system/sepolicy/public/su.te system/sepolicy/public/surfaceflinger.te system/sepolicy/public/system_app.te system/sepolicy/public/system_server.te system/sepolicy/public/tee.te system/sepolicy/public/thermalserviced.te system/sepolicy/public/tombstoned.te system/sepolicy/public/toolbox.te system/sepolicy/public/traced_probes.te system/sepolicy/public/traceur_app.te system/sepolicy/public/tzdatacheck.te system/sepolicy/public/ueventd.te system/sepolicy/public/uncrypt.te system/sepolicy/public/untrusted_app.te system/sepolicy/public/untrusted_v2_app.te system/sepolicy/public/update_engine.te system/sepolicy/public/update_engine_common.te system/sepolicy/public/update_verifier.te system/sepolicy/public/usbd.te system/sepolicy/public/vdc.te system/sepolicy/public/vendor_init.te system/sepolicy/public/vendor_shell.te system/sepolicy/public/vendor_toolbox.te system/sepolicy/public/virtual_touchpad.te system/sepolicy/public/vndservice.te system/sepolicy/public/vndservicemanager.te system/sepolicy/public/vold.te system/sepolicy/public/vold_prepare_subdirs.te system/sepolicy/public/vr_hwc.te system/sepolicy/public/watchdogd.te system/sepolicy/public/webview_zygote.te system/sepolicy/public/wificond.te system/sepolicy/public/wpantund.te system/sepolicy/public/zygote.te system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/reqd_mask.te system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/roles_decl system/sepolicy/public/roles system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/roles system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/users system/sepolicy/reqd_mask/initial_sid_contexts > out/target/product/x86_64/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/plat_pub_policy.conf"

/bin/bash: m4: команда не найдена

[  0% 882/99166] host C: checkfc <= system/sepolicy/tools/checkfc.c

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

07:01:20 ninja failed with: exit status 1



#### failed to build some targets (16:09:50 (hh:mm:ss)) ####
```

Comment: m4: команда не найдена

Comment: Здравствуйте, всё равно не могу понять, что это за ошибка и как её исправить.

Comment: если отсутствует необходимая программа, то её можно, например, установить. говорят, иногда помогает.

Comment: Хорошо, а не подскажите, можно ли возобновить операцию в терминале, т.к. компиляция заняла 16 часов и хотелось бы продолжить её на том моменте, где вылетела ошибка. ПО я установил.

Comment: можно, конечно. кто ж вам запретит?

Comment: А не подскажете команду? я компилировал Android x 86 с помощью lunch android_x86_64-userdebug, а затем указывал количество процессоров для сборки Iso файла : m -j4 iso_img

Comment: понятно: вы опасаетесь, что выполнение той же самой команды может привести к повторной компиляции уже скомпилированных блобов. даже если именно так и написаны гугловские сборочные скрипты, то вряд ли вы (или кто-то другой) когда-нибудь займётся их переписыванием «с нуля». потому вариантов у вас, получается, нет: запускайте и надейтесь на благоразумие разработчиков этих скриптов.

Answer (score 0):

Не хватает инструмента 'm4' на хост системе.

Возможно, вам поможет: https://source.android.com/setup/build/initializing#installing-required-packages-ubuntu-1404.

Ответ взят тут https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/vcKwJ273F6Q

Comment: Хорошо бы основные моменты перенести в сам ответ)

Comment: Не вопрос, поправил.